# Regex: How to match two character but exclude a certain combination

Tags: python, regex

I need help with this Regex. I have a number of file names in the format of:

```
DataFile_en.dat
DataFile_de.dat
DataFile_es.dat
```

It is DateFile_ followed by a two character language code.

**I want to write an regular expression that matches all the filenames with this pattern but not include the English one (DataFile_en.dat)**

I have got this pattern to extract all the files:

```
DataFile_\w{2}.dat
```

But I don't know how to write the pattern to exclude the one with 'en' as language code.  The regular expression will be used in Python.

Comment: `DataFile_([^e].|e[^n])\.dat`

Comment: Is DataFile just an example or is it always the same name? If it is, you don't need a regular expression: `filter(lambda x: x[9:11] != 'en', filelist)`, or similar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a negative look-ahead. You can find more information on what that is [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Essentially, it "looks ahead" and ensures that the regex in the parentheses is not matched.

```
DataFile_(?!en)\w{2}\.dat
```

Note that you should be escaping that period, as it will match any character.

Comment: Good catch with the period :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can use a negative look-ahead.  `(?!something)` means "fail unless you can avoid matching *something*".

```
DataFile_(?!en)\w{2}\.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use `DataFile_(([^e].)|e[^n])).dat`, this stays within the classic "regular language" limit of regular expressions, at the cost of some readability.